# What's the meaning of quote on silverback?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Michael refuses Dry Eye's offer to buy his weed business:

> Dry Eye: You're out of touch. You're forgetting the laws of the
>   jungle, looking down on me. Now, **when the silverback's got more silver
>   than back... he best move on...before he gets moved on**.

What's the meaning of quote on silverback?

I find these line in *The Gentlemen 2019*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The silverback* could refer to [a dominant older human male](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/silverback).

*got more silver* could mean *became more mature*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorilla#Physical_characteristics),

> A silverback is typically more than 12 years of age, and is named for the distinctive patch of silver hair on his back, **which comes with maturity.**

Comment: A silverback specifically refers to a dominant male **gorilla**.  Only metaphorically to an a senior human.